# Unable to send SOAP messages via Java Axis2 when attaching byte array with more than 35KB

Tags: java, apache-axis, soap-client, socketexception

I used wsdl2java to generate the axis2 client stubs for a third party service I wish to access from my jboss server.  I have successfully implemented the required mutual authentication.  As part of this service I am uploading image files between 1-2MB.  They support up to 50MB files, so there should not be any problems on their end.  When I cut my data element off at 35,000 bytes (plus some categorization and xml overhead) it executes in 3-5 seconds and returns the expected results.  However, when I send anything in excess of 35,000 bytes (or 23,000 bytes if I turn off chunking) then after exactly 2 minutes I receive the following stack trace and it does not appear the call is ever sent to the third party server.

```
16:15:14,098 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://soap.service.com/MyService.svc]: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_25]
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621) [axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193) [axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75) [axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404) [axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231) [axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:]
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165) [axis2-kernel-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
at soap.service.MyServiceStub.enroll(MyServiceStub.java:323) [classes:]
at com.client.web.service.MyService.enroll(MyService.java:276) [classes:]
at com.client.web.view.MyBean.doButtonAction(MyBean.java:453) [classes:]
at com.client.web.view.MyBean.doButtonAction(MyBean.java:438) [classes:]
...

16:15:14,135 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection reset
16:15:14,136 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
16:15:14,136 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
16:15:14,136 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
16:15:14,137 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
16:15:14,137 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
16:15:14,137 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
16:15:14,138 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
16:15:14,138 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
16:15:14,138 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
16:15:14,139 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at soap.service.MyServiceStub.enroll(MyServiceStub.java:323)
16:15:14,139 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.client.web.service.MyService.enroll(MyService.java:276)
16:15:14,139 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.client.web.view.MyBean.doButtonAction(MyBean.java:453)
16:15:14,140 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.client.web.view.MyBean.doButtonAction(MyBean.java:438)
16:15:14,140 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:15:14,140 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
16:15:14,141 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:15:14,141 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
16:15:14,141 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)
16:15:14,142 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,142 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)
16:15:14,142 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:127)
16:15:14,143 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:135)
16:15:14,143 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36)
16:15:14,143 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,144 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
16:15:14,144 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36)
16:15:14,144 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,145 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
16:15:14,145 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,145 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SFSBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SFSBInvocationInterceptor.java:58)
16:15:14,146 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,146 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:156)
16:15:14,146 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,147 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:82)
16:15:14,147 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,147 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
16:15:14,148 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,148 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
16:15:14,148 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
16:15:14,149 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,149 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.java:66)
16:15:14,149 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,150 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228)
16:15:14,150 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)
16:15:14,150 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
16:15:14,151 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,151 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
16:15:14,151 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,152 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
16:15:14,152 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,152 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
16:15:14,153 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,153 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32)
16:15:14,154 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,154 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
16:15:14,154 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,155 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
16:15:14,155 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
16:15:14,155 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173)
16:15:14,155 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,156 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.java:52)
16:15:14,156 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
16:15:14,156 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
16:15:14,157 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72)
16:15:14,157 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.client.web.view.MyBean$$$view101.doButtonAction(Unknown Source)
16:15:14,157 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:15:14,158 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
16:15:14,158 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:15:14,158 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
16:15:14,159 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
16:15:14,159 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
16:15:14,159 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
16:15:14,160 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
16:15:14,160 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:111)
16:15:14,160 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
16:15:14,161 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
16:15:14,161 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.client.web.view.MyBean$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.doButtonAction(MyBean$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
16:15:14,161 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.client.web.view.MyBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doButtonAction(MyBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
16:15:14,162 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
16:15:14,162 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
16:15:14,162 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:15:14,163 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
16:15:14,163 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
16:15:14,163 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
16:15:14,164 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
16:15:14,164 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
16:15:14,164 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
16:15:14,165 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
16:15:14,165 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
16:15:14,165 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
16:15:14,165 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
16:15:14,166 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
16:15:14,166 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
16:15:14,166 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
16:15:14,167 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
16:15:14,167 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
16:15:14,167 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
16:15:14,168 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
16:15:14,168 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
16:15:14,168 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
16:15:14,169 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
16:15:14,169 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
16:15:14,169 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
16:15:14,170 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489)
16:15:14,170 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
16:15:14,170 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
16:15:14,171 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
16:15:14,171 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
16:15:14,171 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
16:15:14,172 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
16:15:14,172 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
16:15:14,172 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
16:15:14,172 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
16:15:14,173 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
16:15:14,173 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
16:15:14,173 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
16:15:14,174 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
16:15:14,174 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
16:15:14,174 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
16:15:14,174 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
16:15:14,175 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
16:15:14,175 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
16:15:14,175 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
16:15:14,176 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
16:15:14,176 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
16:15:14,176 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
16:15:14,177 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
16:15:14,177 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
16:15:14,177 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
16:15:14,178 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
16:15:14,178 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
16:15:14,178 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
16:15:14,178 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
16:15:14,179 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
16:15:14,179 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
16:15:14,179 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
16:15:14,180 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)  ... 112 more
```

I have tried messing with options (timeouts, chunked, MTOM, SwA, etc.) without much effect.  Any help figuring out where this limitation is coming from and how to remove it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So a connection reset is a connection reset :-/ (i find nothing actual regarding this and jboss) what about the third party - do they maybe cutoff? by "data" we talk about a byte[] (base64 encoded element)? ..and when it is not the third party, further configuration details will be helpful,

Comment: base64 encoded byte[] - yes. Not jboss - most likely (I removed that tag).  I'm calling the setData(byte[]) method generated by wsdl2java.  As I understand it, the generated code is doing the translation to base64 somewhere down the line.  What additional configuration details would help?

Comment: you could post: relevant parts of the wsdl, your invocation code, axis configuration, ... but in the end, i fear the problem might be in your network/infrastructure: What says the "guy in charge of your firewall"?

Comment: I have tested this both in my local development environment (macbook pro) and in my production environment (Open Shift).  Hence, no "guy in charge of my firewall".  The stack trace varies a little between environments, but the connection reset still occurs between 35-36K on both platforms.  I can send and receive much larger amounts of data using REST, but not via SOAP.

Comment: I do not see anything in the wsdl or invocation code that could be causing this problem.  My axis configuration is simply copying the src and resource files generated by wsdl2java into my project, adding axis2-jaxws, axis2-xmlbeans, axis2-transport-local, and axis2-transport-html to my pom and then adding the necessary mutual authentication logic to my implementation.  Did I perchance get the wrong axis jars or miss an axis configuration step somewhere?